# Optimal choice of matrix element subset

Tags: matrices, optimization, summation, algorithms, linear-programming

Let's suppose that we have an $n \times n$ matrix $M$ containing only strictly positive elements $m_{ij}$. Is there a fast algorithm/procedure that finds the subset of elements 
$$m_{i_{\nu}j_{\nu}}$$
$$i_{\nu}=i_{\mu} \text{, } j_{\nu}=j_{\mu} \iff \nu = \mu$$
$$ \nu \in [1, n]$$ that minimizes the sum $$\sum_{\nu=1}^{n} m_{i_{\nu}j_{\nu}}$$
So with words: how can I choose $n$ elements out of a positive matrix, such that I only use one element from each row and column and the sum of these elements is minimal?

Comment: This is an instance of the "assignment problem"; you can use the "Hungarian algorithm" to solve it.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was searching for!